# How to write unit test case for switch case in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am new to writing test cases for Angular 10, this is my component function code. How to write test cases for switch case. Would appreciate guidance on the same

```
public Mreceived(event) {
    switch (event && event['event']) {
      case 'OptionSelected':
        this.dongleNext();  //private function inside component
        break;

      case 'tempSelected':
        break;
    }
  }
```

as per guidance wrote test case as follows

```
it('should call dongleNext on onOptionSelected event', () => {
    component.Mreceived({ event: 'OptionSelected' });
    //@ts-ignore
    expect(spyOn(component, 'dongleNext')).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

it fails saying  Expected spy toggleNext to have been called ,can anyone guide on this please

Answer (score 0):

like any other jasmine unit test

```
it('event shall be OptionSelected', () => {
    // Initialization of subject under test here
    // call business functionality, i.e. Mreceived({event: 'OptionSelected'})
    // Check if expectation has been met.
});
```

updated: OP wants to validate call of private functionality.

```
...
spyOn<any>(component, 'dongleNext');
expect(component['dongleNext']).toHaveBeenCalled();
...
```

Comment: that i did @phhbr but how can i know if the method dongleNext was called as it is a private method

Comment: If you really want that (bad design - you shall only care about the change of your method), you can do something like in the updated answer...

it has nothing to do with your initial question tho